# Visualizing Source

Tags: c++, architecture, diagram, flowchart

I'm trying to understand an application but its documentation really doesn't give me a good overview of how it works, 
so my question is : 
how can I get a diagram / flowchart / runtime architecture pic based on the source code ? It's C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl) is a reasonable way to approach the problem.

Comment: thx I just gave it a try but the app is huge and so is the output. I guess I'll have to step by step through it...